# How to enable experimental reverse port forwarding in chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, port, adb

> Commonly you have a web server running on your local development
>   machine, and you want to connect to that site from your device. If the
>   mobile device and the development machine are on the same network,
>   this is straightforward. But this may be difficult in some cases, like
>   on a restricted corporate network.

This is what I ran into at work.I have been trying to get my web application that runs on my my localhost to be accessible on my mobile device.

- Desktop OS: Mac OS X 10.6.8
- Desktop Chrome: Version 30.0.1599.69
- Mobile OS: Android 4.3 (Nexus4)
- Mobile Chrome: Version 30.0.1599.82

I found an [article](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging?hl=ru#reverse-port-forwarding) about chrome experimental features that was explaining you how to enable **reverse port forwarding** in chrome. I have been following the article until it said to tick the checkbox for "Enable reverse port forwarding" in "developer tools > settings > experiments". **I found the tick list but could not find that option.** Does anyone know how I can enable this reverse port forwarding?

Comment: Check `chrome://flags`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @SLaks. But I know about `chrome://flags` as it is mentioned in the article I am revering to in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Often you also need to experimental devtools features in chrome://flags/#enable-devtools-experiments

[image: experiemental]

And now the reverse port forwarding is on chrome://inspect

[image: inspect]

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Kinlan. According to the article (see link in original post) I should have an option saying "enable REVERSE port forwarding". See https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging/settings-experiments.png

Comment: It is the same thing, this will let you set up an IP address that you can go to on your phone that is hosted on your machine.

Comment: It is the same thing. Thank you @Kinlan